# How select users who submit for approval

Tags: approval-process

How can I get user id of ProcessInstance object, user who submit object for approval in approval process?

Comment: During which step?

Comment: I need show table of approveId, object id for approve and user who submit for approve.
I use:
List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem> processInstanceWorkItems = [SELECT OriginalActorId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId, 
 ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinitionId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem WHERE ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'];
Where ProcessDefinitionId  is id of approve, TargetObjectId is id of object ofr approve. But I dont know how find user who submit this object for approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the `createdbyid` field since the person submitting for approval is kicking off the approval process and creating the record.

Comment: One user can create record and second, who has access, can submit for approval.

Comment: But the createdbyid field on ProcessInstanceWorkItem will always be who submitted for approval.

Comment: I didnt think about it. You realy help me. Thank you.